# waze geocoding service results returns mistaken location on leaflet map

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, leaflet

i have been using [openstreetmap geocoding service](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&accept-language=he) to display points on a [leaflet based map](http://map.tautktiv.com/map/%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8/%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C).
so far so good, but the geocoding service is missing some data for streets in Israel.
so im trying to set up a redundant display for that issing openstreetmap data by querying the [WAZE geocoding service](http://www.waze.co.il/WAS/mozi?token=123) .

problem is, the lon/lat and boundaries data received from waze point on the map to a place which is off by a few kilometers (same city but wrong address)
does anyone know why this happens ? is it basically possible to use my approach or does every map have its own absolute lon/lat tiles positioning  ?
thanks

here is an example when querying the same street in jerusalem:

[openstreetmap query](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&accept-language=he&limit=1&q=%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D)

[waze query](http://www.waze.co.il/WAS/mozi?token=123&q=%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D)

here is the correct [OSM result](http://map.tautktiv.com/map/%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C) on the map.

here is the incorrect [waze result](http://map.tautktiv.com/devmap/%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C) on the map (showing some street in Haifa, 200km from jerusalem)

Comment: Could you give an example, perhaps an address and the coordinates returned from WAZE and the corresponding coordinates on OSM or Google. In general geographical coordinates are absolute.

Comment: Lat/Lon are clearly defined and every map and every GPS device will use the same. Only the projection can be different but that doesn't explain your issue.

Comment: i added some examples